# Delta of timestamp within a group is higher than threshold

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a telemetry table that has list of request id's, time at which certain activity happened for that request. Here is a simplified sequence of activities done for a request:
`authUser -> processInput -> calculateRate -> returnResponse` and the E2E on average takes ~3 seconds.
At times, certain requests are stuck longer in an activity which I need to figure out (output would be list of req_id, activity that took longer than a threshold). The table contains millions of records so if I sort by Req_id and do a `prev()` to compare delta by Req_id fails due to sorting memory limit.
Any better ways to write this query?

Sample input:

| Req_Id | Req_time | Activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Guid**1** | 2022-12-01T01:01:0**1** | authUser |
| Guid**1** | 2022-12-01T01:01:0**1** | processInput |
| Guid**2** | 2022-12-01T01:01:0**1** | authUser |
| Guid**1** | 2022-12-01T01:01:0**2** | calculateRate |
| Guid**2** | 2022-12-01T01:01:0**3** | processInput |
| Guid**3** | 2022-12-01T01:01:0**3** | authUser |
| Guid**2** | 2022-12-01T01:01:0**4** | calculateRate |
| Guid**3** | 2022-12-01T01:01:0**4** | processInput |
| Guid**2** | 2022-12-01T01:01:0**5** | returnResponse |
| .. | .. | .. |
| .. | .. | .. |
| Guid**3** | 2022-12-01T01:01:**20** | calculateRate |
| Guid**3** | 2022-12-01T01:01:**21** | returnResponse |

Expected output:

`input`
`| where delta_of_activity_duration > 5 second`

| Req_Id | Activity | Duration(sec) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Guid3 | calculateRate | 16 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [partition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/partitionoperator) operator to do the calculation per *Req_Id*.

```
datatable(Req_Id:string, Req_time:datetime, Activity:string)
[
    "Guid1" ,datetime(2022-12-01T01:01:01) ,"authUser"
   ,"Guid1" ,datetime(2022-12-01T01:01:01) ,"processInput"
   ,"Guid2" ,datetime(2022-12-01T01:01:01) ,"authUser"
   ,"Guid1" ,datetime(2022-12-01T01:01:02) ,"calculateRate"
   ,"Guid2" ,datetime(2022-12-01T01:01:03) ,"processInput"
   ,"Guid3" ,datetime(2022-12-01T01:01:03) ,"authUser"
   ,"Guid2" ,datetime(2022-12-01T01:01:04) ,"calculateRate"
   ,"Guid3" ,datetime(2022-12-01T01:01:04) ,"processInput"
   ,"Guid2" ,datetime(2022-12-01T01:01:05) ,"returnResponse"
   ,"Guid3" ,datetime(2022-12-01T01:01:20) ,"calculateRate"
   ,"Guid3" ,datetime(2022-12-01T01:01:21) ,"returnResponse"
]
| partition hint.strategy=shuffle by Req_Id
  (
    order by Req_time asc
    | extend duration = (Req_time - prev(Req_time))/1s
    | where duration >= 5
  )
```

| Req_Id | Req_time | Activity | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Guid3 | 2022-12-01T01:01:20Z | calculateRate | 16 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA7WSTWvDMAyG7/kVIqcEki1220sgg51Gr2E7jTHSWG0MmZPZcrdAf/zsrO12KG0o1B9gW3r0vhiJitxctRiV+Pm+FLkhLdUmAX8l+YG5qAj9IYHHmuRW0rDPiYPXANwIn6wULITkkBnxjPOU8TRjzxnLxxVDElaWmheDOvRYMhnrdVejMUvVW/qH8psoco/VVVvb1iWVbk+XnJ1xO5uAnnB7QXF+zu0Fyfn1f7vwqEayWpVo+k6Z6bo8u94zZ6eE34Id9JUmSbJT0EhFd65BXZHNUJjGrtctwmqA3/52UtHYtZ0WqA/vXg4qU4+RHeA3oRIgrKviaxYQHbNS6DVuj/c4vmdmj301qPGPeihg4SLxD1oZGHNjAwAA)

Comment: Thanks David. Partition is hitting resource limit as well:
`Query execution has exceeded the allowed limits (80DA0001): 'partition' operator has exceeded the memory budget (5368709120) during evaluation. 
 clientRequestId: KustoWebV2;53d014a2-3dbb-4b1b-a780-a06cb12e70a0`

Comment: For millions of records?... see updated answer (hint.strategy=shuffle)

Comment: Thanks. Did improve but does hit the memory limit if I query beyond a day.

Comment: Accept this answer and post a new question. For the new question please provide a sample data that represents the actual data accurately, info about the data demographic (number of records per day,  avg & max, number of records per Req_Id, how many records do you expect to get as a result etc.), and details about your cluster capacity.

Comment: Sure. Wondering if you would you be able to pull that from the clientRequestId shared above?